# Bones are doing almost the complete opposite when choosing paste pose flipped

Tags: animation

This feels like another weird one. Previously I asked a similar question and I got the answer and everything was fine. However this is completely different. The last model I used kept flipping across the map I was using and its work around was just highlighting the leg bones and copying their pose alone. I'm trying to do the same thing with this one yet the results are below. I've also tried including the root bone in the transformation, as well as the entire model as well, unlocking the location and rotation, yet the same thing happens.

How do I get it to actually flip the pose instead of breaking his legs?

Update: Added picutes of him breaking his legs. Moving his right leg results in it gliding with the move tool as it should. However his left leg snaps to a different position immediately upon being moved and looks like how it does in the picture. Also I am not sure how to share just the Armature. Very new to blender lol.

[image: Contact pose.]
[image: What blender thinks the flipped pose is.]
[image: His legs normally.]
[image: Right leg behaves normally.]
[image: Left leg is doing the stanky leg.]

Comment: Hello please share your armature only: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Are you using the correct [naming convention](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/armatures/bones/editing/naming.html#naming-conventions) for the bones on the left and right side of the body? If the bones names don't comply with Blender's naming convention mirroring won't work.

Comment: The names for the thighs are leg left thigh and leg right thigh. They seem to be conventional unless Blender's detection is pretty strict on the names.

Comment: SOLVED IT! I accidentally locked its location to the y axis.

Comment: That definitely wouldn't help! :^)